# How to capture an image(url) inside iframe?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

Here I am trying to capture the image(url) inside an iframe. But it is not working. Here is my code:

```html
<div id="iframe">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="border2">
        <tr>
            <td height="403">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <iframe id="IFTrendAnalysis" name="IFTrendAnalysis" scrolling="auto" runat="server" width="100%" height="403" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNSalesTrendChart" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and image path(generated dynamically)

> http://10.232.151.132:8080/pentaho/getImage?image=picture658447691538512233.png

and

```
$(function () {
    $("#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis img").click(function () {
        var update = $("<div>").append(
            $("<img>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))
        ).html();

        $("#content").val(function (i, v) {
            return v + update;
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Accessing iframe content can be an issue if both pages are not on the same domain (it will cause various issues in different browser too that's why iframe must be avoided when possible)

Comment: ok what is the work around for iframe in dotnet to pass src

Comment: Best way to deal with this is to use AJAX to load the other page inside a div element instead, that way it is part of the same page and you can grab it like any other element. Then assigning the source should be no issue. Keep in mind that pages injected often have there javascript stripped out.

Comment: Won't ajax also cause cross-domain issues, unless you create a "middle man" page?

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe page is  within the same domain as parent page, then this should help you:

```
var name = "img_Sample";
$('#MainContent_iframeDetail').get(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById(name).src
```

I assume, you should be able to use Jquery in place of `document.getElementByID` as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').find('img').live('click', function () {
                var obj = $(this);

                $('#content').val(function (i, value) {
                    if (($.trim(value).length === 0) || ($('<div>' + value + '</div>').find('[src="' + obj.attr('src') + '"]').length === 0)) {
                        return value + $('<div></div>').append($('<img />', { 'src': obj.attr('src') })).html();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#imgExistMessage').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);

                        return value;
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="imgExistMessage" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; color: Red;
        display: none;">Image has been already selected.</span>
    <br />
    <textarea id="content" cols="50" rows="20">   
    </textarea>
    <div id="MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZkMSKCbY0Y8/TRCpCX5p35I/AAAAAAAAABQ/ZL2nsL-ir7U/s277/3.jpg"
            width="100" height="100" />
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y301Ju4n32g/TRCtzBfoiZI/AAAAAAAAABc/3tGEuAD3R8I/w487-h365-k/51.jpg"
            width="100" height="100" />
        <img src="../../Images/Desert.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <!--  <iframe id="MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis" src="http://api.jquery.com/append/" width="300px"
        height="500px"></iframe>-->
</body>
</html>

    enter code here
```